# undefined assignment when the right side of the assigment has a value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component in angular that consumes a service on `ngOnInit` function. When I call a method from the service, it returns an array of elements and assigns it to a `t` variable and I confirmed that it is returning the array, but I took the `t` variable and assigned it to a typed variable but after the assignment, the typed variable keep with undefined value.

Component:

```
export class HeroesFilteredComponent implements OnInit {

  private heroes:Heroe[];
  private termino:string;

  constructor(
    private _heroesService:HeroesService, 
    private _activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params =>{
      let t =  this._heroesService.searchHeroes(params['g']);
      this.heroes = t;
    });
    console.log(this.heroes.length);
  }

}
```

Service:

```
 @Injectable()
    export class HeroesService {

    private heroes:Heroe[] = [{...},...,{...}]

    searchHeroes(termino:string):Heroe[]{
      termino = termino.toLowerCase();
      return this.heroes;
    }
}
```

interface:

```
export interface Heroe{
    nombre:string;
    bio:string;
    img:string;
    aparicion:string;
    casa:string;
    index?:number;
}
```

When I check `t`, it has value.

Why this strange behavior?

Comment: That code isn't enough information to give an answer. Are there async processes in play?

Comment: You'll have to provide more code because what you described does not make sense with a simple piece of code like what you posted.

Comment: Oks, let me edit.

Comment: @julianzapata, can you replicate this on a Sample StackBlitz?

Answer (score 3):

`console.log(this.heroes.length);` is written outside the `subscribe` block in `HeroesFilteredComponent`. That's the reason it is coming as undefined.

Move it inside the `subscribe` block and it should print the correct value.

```
export class HeroesFilteredComponent implements OnInit {

  private heroes: Heroe[];
  private termino: string;

  constructor(
    private _heroesService: HeroesService,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      let t = this._heroesService.searchHeroes(params['g']);
      this.heroes = t;
      console.log(this.heroes.length);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: but i am refering to the scoped parameter. I am just modifing its value. I tried your solution, but i had the same error.

Comment: @julianzapata, the `console.log` line was written outside the `subscribe` block. The code inside the `subscribe` block is going to run after the `console.log`. Since the `console.log` is going to run even before the `heroes` property is set on the component, hence you're seeing undefined on the console for that.

Comment: Thanks @siddAjmera. Really, this wasn't the problem but help me to figure it out. The reason was because I never pass a value to the input variable to another component, but i never looked there because this undefined value when I was debugging and I was relationing this with the error.